# How to check if random fact is a specific string?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot using Discord.JS and I'm working on a command called 'throw', and pretty much what it does is when you type the command >throw User, the bot responds back with "[User] threw [something] at [Mentioned User].", inside [something] would be something random from the `var facts`.

How would I be able to check if it picked a specific thing from the random list of facts. so for example I have `var facts = ['snowball','reindeer','gift','Mistletoe'].` and if **Mistletoe** was choosen, then it'd send a different message.

here's my code.

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

      module.exports = {
        name: 'throw',
        description: 'Throws something random at someone or yourself!',                     
        usage: '[User]',
        cooldown: 2,        
        execute(message, args) {
            let Mentions = message.mentions.users.first();
            var facts = ["Snowball","Reindeer","Gift","Mistletoe"];
            var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);          
            message.delete({ timeout: 0, reason: 'Clear Command Message.' });
    if (Mentions != null) {      
      if(facts === "Mistletoe"{ //If facts is Mistletoe, then send this message.
        message.channel.send(message.member.user.username + ` just threw ` + facts[fact] + ` at <@` + Mentions + `>, that means they have to use the \`${prefix}kiss\` command on each-other.`);
      }else{ //If facts is something else, then send this instead.
      message.channel.send(message.member.user.username + ` just threw ` + facts[fact] + ` at <@` + Mentions + `>`);
      }  
    } else {
      if(facts === "Mistletoe"){
        message.channel.send(message.member.user.username + ` just threw ` + facts[fact] + ` at themselves, that means they have to use the \`${prefix}kiss\` command on themself.`);
      }else{
        message.channel.send(message.member.user.username + " just threw " + facts[fact] + " at themselves."); 
            }
           
      }
        },
    };
```

I'm a beginner at this sort of stuff, so apology for the messy code, hopefully I explained well what I'm asking here.

Comment: `if(facts === "Mistletoe"{` should be `if(facts[fact] === "Mistletoe"){` (also notice the `)`)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it, don't know why I didn't think to add `[fact]` to it, and also thanks for the correction. @LawrenceCherone